# Robolectric intermitten NPE crash failure at org.robolectric.res.ResBundle$Value.compareTo(ResBundle.java:189)

Tags: android, robolectric

I have intermitten failure when running my test.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.robolectric.res.ResBundle$Value.compareTo(ResBundle.java:189)
    at org.robolectric.res.ResBundle$Value.compareTo(ResBundle.java:166)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:320)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:188)
```

On the below code

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner::class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig::class, sdk = intArrayOf(21), packageName = "my.package")
class MyActivityTest {
    lateinit var myActivity : MyActivity

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        myActivity = MyActivity()
    }
}
```

Specifically on line

```
        myActivity = MyActivity()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the fix is

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner::class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig::class, sdk = intArrayOf(21), packageName = "my.package")
class MyActivityTest {
    lateinit var myActivity : MyActivity

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        myActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity::class.java).get()
    }
}
```